# Angular2: [routerLinkActive]="['active']" not updating on _router.navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an app with several routerLinks, I style them with `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`. When I navigate by clicking one of the `routerLinks` everything works fine. When I navigate using:

`this._router.navigate( [ thisUrl ], {queryParams: queryParams } );`

the `routerLinkActive` stop working. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I am using angular2 2.4.1

Comment: Can you setup an example plnkr

Comment: I have similar problem. Check this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/cwXf7NcVUdoNbipK1zD7/) forked from the official angular example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this._router.navigate( [ thisUrl ], {queryParams: queryParams, relativeTo: this.route } );
```

where this.route is injected into the component in the constructor.

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

And make thisUrl relative to the route with a relative path like '../' + thisUrl